# What does linux-headers-`uname -r` do?

Tags: apt

What does the following command do?

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

`sudo` executes the statement with elevated priviledges. `apt-get` is a command to retrieve a specific package/program. What does the rest of the switches/flags do?

I'm trying to reset my wireless adapter's drivers to "factory default" settings.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### `--reinstall install`:

Normally, this is written `install --reinstall`, but both work just fine. This simply is telling `apt-get` to reinstall the package(s).

### `linux-headers-`:

`linux-headers-` is the beginning of a package name. If you run `dpkg -l | grep linux-headers-` you can see a full list of any packages installed that begin with that:

[image]

Header files are, from the [GNU site](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Header-Files.html):

> A header file is a file containing C declarations and macro
>   definitions to be shared between several source files. You request the
>   use of a header file in your program by including it, with the C
>   preprocessing directive ‘#include’.

And, as you can see from the response from `dpkg -l | grep linux-headers-`, the packages that start with `linux-headers-` are the header files for the Linux kernel.

### `` `uname -r` ``:

This is what is known as [Command Substitution](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_30.html). (The link is to the faqs.org page about the BASH command substitution capabilities.)

This runs the `uname -r` command, which returns the current kernel version:

[image]

and then puts what is returned from the `uname -r` command into the `` sudo apt-get --reinstall install linux-headers-`uname -r` `` command.

From the faqs.org page:

> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the
>   command itself. Command substitution occurs when a command is enclosed
>   as follows:
>
> ```
> $(command)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> `command`
> ```
>
> Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the
>   command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any
>   trailing newlines deleted.

Also, see [this Unix/Linux Q/A about understand BASH backticks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48392/understanding-backtick).

Now, you don't see this happen - you just see the results. However, if you *did* see the command after the `uname -r` response was put into the command, this is somewhat it would look like (changing for your current kernel version obviously):

`sudo apt-get --reinstall install linux-headers-3.16.0-31-generic`

---

### Simplified version:

You're telling apt-get to reinstall the linux-headers package for your current kernel version.

Comment: golden, thanks for the detail! would +1 this if i could ...

Comment: @culturalanomoly Well, edit 1-2 posts and accept this one and you'll have enough rep to do so! ;) Welcome to Ask Ubuntu :)

Comment: btw, what'd you use to redact the sensitive bits on the image?

Comment: @culturalanomoly I use [Shutter](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/shutter/). It's an awesome piece of software that lets you takes all sorts of different screenshots and then has a built-in editor for doing stuff like, as you saw, blurring bits, drawing arrows, circling things, adding text. It's one of the most useful pieces of software I have installed.